# PrimeNG datatable cols with nested json object

Tags: angular, datatable, primeng

I've a directive for creating table using PrimeNG p-datatable:

```
<p-dataTable paginatorPosition="top" scrollable="true" scrollHeight="200px" 
   [value]="table.cells" resizableColumns="true" [loading]="loading">
            <p-column *ngFor="let col of table.headers" [field]="col.field" [header]="col.header" [sortable]="col.sortable" [style]="{'width':'230px'}">
                ...
```

Inside service a create an entity like this:

```
        header = new MyTableHeaders();
        header.header = "Col Head"
        header.field = "field";
        header.sortable = false;
...
```

The is when I've a nested object to pass in, like this:

```
name: "name",
address: {
   city: "city",
   street: "street",
   ...
```

I tried to pass:

```
header = new MyTableHeaders();
header.header = "Col Head"
header.field = "address.city";
header.sortable = false;
```

or

```
header = new MyTableHeaders();
header.header = "Col Head"
header.field = "address[city]";
header.sortable = false;
```

but no value appears in col. Can you help me?
Thanks

Answer (score -1):

I think you have to change your p-column to include a ng-template...
Have a look at

```
<p-column field="Sessions" [editable]="true" header="Start Date">              
    <ng-template let-col let-sessions="rowData" let-ri="rowIndex" pTemplate="body">
     <div>
       <p>{{sessions.Sessions[0].StartDateTime | date: 'd,MMM,yyyy'}}</p>
      </div>
    </ng-template>
</p-column>
```

for an example. See also [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43422858)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.